# Java printing issue

Tags: java, ubuntu, printing

I'm trying to print a HTML String under Ubuntu 10.10 using Java,
using this code:

```
public void printHTMLText(String text) throws Exception {
    if (printerName.equals(""))
        throw new Exception("no standart printer");
    PrintService printService = getCurrentPrinter();

    if (printService == null)
        helperFunctions
                .errorOut("Couldn't print HTML-Text: "
                        + text
                        + " because no current printer is given or current printer is not available");
    else {
        DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();
        DocFlavor[] avail = printService.getSupportedDocFlavors();
        DocFlavor htmlutf8 = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < avail.length; i++) {
            if (avail[i].toString().equals(
                    "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"; class=\"[B\""))
                htmlutf8 = avail[i];
            helperFunctions.debugOut(avail[i].toString());
        }

        SimpleDoc doc;
        try {
            if (htmlutf8 == null)
                throw new PrintException(
                        "Sorry the chosen printer can't deliever text/html; charset=utf-8");
            // helperFunctions.debugOut(htmlutf8.getMimeType());

            doc = new SimpleDoc(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), new DocFlavor(
                    htmlutf8.getMimeType(),
                    htmlutf8.getRepresentationClassName()), null);

            printJob.print(doc, null);
            helperFunctions.infoOut("Printing HTML: " + text);

        } catch (PrintException ex) {
            helperFunctions.errorOut(ex.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

HTML Printing is, according to getSupportedDocFlavors(), supported.
I get no Java Errors and the printer responds. But all I get is an empty page.

What I'm doing wrong?
Did cost me quite some hours already and have no clue, since Java doesn't report any error.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Updated pastelink, because it was expired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going with [JTextComponent#print](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print%28%29). Even if your program isn't Swing related. 
[JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) has HTML support and extends `JTextComponent` so it best fits the job.
Oracle Tutorial about printing: [How to Print Text](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtext.html).

Comment: hi, I can't test right now, but it looks like the print function opens a printing dialog. But since this is a server program and will be instructed from an android tablet, it is a plain console program and shouldn't have to need some graphical user interface or user interaction.

Comment: There is a overloaded [print](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print%28java.text.MessageFormat,%20java.text.MessageFormat,%20boolean,%20javax.print.PrintService,%20javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet,%20boolean%29) method which accepts a `showPrintDialog` boolean attribute. If your server have some kind of GUI layer (or even desktop emulation) it shall be ok to use this method. Just expose a web-service or something to activate the printing function.

Comment: And from the Javadocs: "Note: In headless mode, showPrintDialog and interactive parameters are ignored and no dialogs are shown."